# Exclude value from an array in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, random

I have a list of values, selected 4 of them randomly and now want to exclude those four random values from the main list. How can I do that in Python?

```
Main_list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
random_list = random.sample(xrange(10), 4)
selected_values = [0,0,0,0];
for i in range(0, len(random_list)):
    selected_values[i] = Main_list[random_list[i]]
print 'selected values:', selected_values
```

results would be like: selected values: [2, 5, 9, 3]

So now how to exclude the randomly selected value from the main list?

Comment: You mean exclude your `selected_values` to your `Main_list`?

Comment: `Main_list = [val for val in Main_list if val not in selected_values]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems simpler than you're trying to make it:

```
from random import sample

main_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print("Main list:", main_list)

selected_values = sample(main_list, 4)
print("Selected values:", selected_values)

for selected_value in selected_values:
    main_list.remove(selected_value)

print("Main list:", main_list)
```

Comment: `remove()` removes the first matching element, not the one that was selected (in case of same elements being present in the list).

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a different approach. Make a list, shuffle the list to make it random, then `pop()` values from the list, automatically removing them.

```
from random import shuffle

main_list = range(1,11) # 1..10
shuffle( main_list )

four_values = [main_list.pop() for i in range(4)]

print four_values
```

Answer (score 0):

try this its working for me

```
import random
Main_list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

rand_items = [Main_list[random.randrange(len(Main_list))]
              for item in range(4)]
print("selected values from list",rand_items)

def Remove(duplicate): 
    final_list = [] 
    for num in duplicate: 
        if num not in final_list: 
            final_list.append(num) 
    return final_list 


for i in Remove(rand_items):
    Main_list.remove(i)
print("after removing items from list",Main_list)
```

output of my code is:

selected values from list [4, 3, 9, 2]

after removing items from list [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]

Comment: Thank you guys, all of ur answers are working well. However, I am going for simplest one for me. 
Regards,